# using ng2-translate with jhipster, Property 'parser' is private in type 'TranslateService' but not in type 'TranslateService'

Tags: angular, jhipster, ngx-translate, ng2-translate

i'm using angular-cli as a client for Jhipster, and when i try to build my project i have a probleme on Translate module, i tried to upgrade to ngx-translate but i still having the same problem.

here is the error i got :

'TranslateService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TranslateService'.

shared-common.module.ts :

```
    import { NgModule, Sanitizer } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { TranslateService } from 'ng2-translate';
import { AlertService } from 'ng-jhipster';
import {
    CarcheckappSharedLibsModule,
    JhiLanguageHelper,
    FindLanguageFromKeyPipe,
    JhiAlertComponent,
    JhiAlertErrorComponent
} from './';

export function alertServiceProvider(sanitizer: Sanitizer,
                                     translateService: TranslateService) {
    // set below to true to make alerts look like toast
    const isToast = false;
    return new AlertService(sanitizer, isToast, translateService);
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CarcheckappSharedLibsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        FindLanguageFromKeyPipe,
        JhiAlertComponent,
        JhiAlertErrorComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        JhiLanguageHelper,
        {
            provide: AlertService,
            useFactory: alertServiceProvider,
            deps: [Sanitizer, TranslateService]
        },
        Title
    ],
    exports: [
        CarcheckappSharedLibsModule,
        FindLanguageFromKeyPipe,
        JhiAlertComponent,
        JhiAlertErrorComponent
    ]
})
export class CarcheckappSharedCommonModule {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong package.

```
import { TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

The `AlertService` expects `TranslateService` from `@ngx-translate/core`, you cannot swap it with another one. 
   If you want to use `ng2-translate` you have to create your own `AlertService`.

Comment: i imported TranslateService from @ngx-translate/core, but i still have the same error message : Property 'parser' is private in type 'TranslateService' but not in type 'TranslateService'.

Comment: Well, then you are still using ng2-translate since ngx-translate doesn't have a property 'parser'